# Securing Javascript (server side?)

Tags: javascript, client-side, server-side

We have a project with a lot of proprietary calculations which we would rather not have downloadbable. Unfortunately the project was developed using tools that render the project in Javascript.

Is there any way to take browser based Javascript and put it on a server-side application that will render the HTML for the browser?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at NodeJs? https://nodejs.org/en/

It's server side javascript

Comment: Yes, but does it actually do HTML rendering?  Things like classic rewrite contents of a div container?

Comment: @MichaelBissell That's a different question: client-side rendering obviously has to happen on the client side, even if it's just sticking server-side-rendered HTML into a div. It's not yet clear what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: We have a team of researchers who found a tool that allows them to create a custom, interactive web application based on their math and source data. The team using the tool is not a development team but was able to create a pretty cool app that would be difficult to rebuild from scratch. 

If the entire app is running in a Rhino or node container I assume it can still render on the server side, and display, as long as it knows how to interpret what is traditionally client-side code. One of those theory/practice things... sounds like we can do it in theory... but no idea how in practice

Comment: How about also using PhantomJs http://phantomjs.org/? It's a browser without any UI, usually used for testing JavaScript